# Find the largest image dimensions from list of images

Tags: python

I have a list (the paths) of images saved locally. How can I find the largest image from these? I'm not referring to the file size but the dimensions.

All the images are in common web-compatible formats — JPG, GIF, PNG, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (PIL). Something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
filenames = ['/home/you/Desktop/chstamp.jpg', '/home/you/Desktop/something.jpg']
sizes = [Image.open(f, 'r').size for f in filenames]
max(sizes)
```

**Update** (Thanks [delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395760/delnan)):

Replace last two lines of above snippet with:

```
max(Image.open(f, 'r').size for f in filenames)
```

**Update 2**

The OP wants to find the index of the file corresponding to the largest dimensions. This requires some help from [`numpy`](http://www.scipy.org/NumPy). See below:

```
from numpy import array
image_array = array([Image.open(f, 'r').size for f in filenames])
print image_array.argmax()
```

Comment: That should really be `max(Image.open(f, 'r').size for f in filenames)` (generator expression!).

Comment: Thanks Manoj. I like the method of yours using lambda functions. In this exmaple, can i also get the index/location of the image that was the largest?
I could always write a `for` loop to iterate over the whole thing but my method isn't as clean and concise as yours.

Comment: @Mridang: Eh, lambda? Don't you mean list comprehension?

Comment: @Mridang: Updated my answer to find index of largest image. See above.

Comment: @Mridang: Delnan is correct; I used list comprehension and not lambda.

Comment: @delnan/@Manoj: My bad. That's what i meant. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I like your solution but it means using an additonal library. Would it considered kludy if i tried to get the index by this using `largest = max(sizes)`. `sizes.index(largest)`. This would give us the index in the sizes array which has the largest value. Since the second array is built by iterating over the first array, the indices would be in sync and the index of the largest value in the second array would correspond to the index of the image in the first. What's your take on this? I'm not handling scenarions where more than image has the same dimensions.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the "size" of an image is its area :

```
from PIL import Image

def get_img_size(path):
    width, height = Image.open(path).size
    return width*height

largest = max(the_paths, key=get_img_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need PIL.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(image_file)
width, height = img.size
```

Once you have the size of a single image, checking the whole list and selecting the bigger one is not the problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
import Image

src = Image.open(image)
size = src.size
```

size will be a tuple with the image dimensions (witdh and height)